# How to automatically close an InfoWindows

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use google map api for my personnal web photo gallery.
For each pictures with gps coordinates, I add a Maker object on a map and an InfoWindows object associated with the marker to show a thumbnail when I click on the marker with mouse.

My question :
How to automatically close an InfoWindows when I click on other Marker ?
In another word, when I click on a marker, I want to close all other InfoWindows opened before.

You can see some tests here : http://avbo7291.o2switch.net/outils/test-google-map-api.html

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single instance of InfoWindow and just set new content on marker click like so:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent("Hello World 1 !");
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent("Hello World 2 !");
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Then you can attach a click event to the map itself to close this infowindow:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
    infowindow.close();
});
```